# Getting identity of the transaction creator in smart contract?

Tags: java, corda

How can I get the identity of the transaction creator in the smart contract? (e.g. If state1 has `status = "ISSUE"` and only a specific identity is allowed to move from state1 to state2 where `state1.status = "ISSUE"`.)

what would be ideal way to design such requirement in corda?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the identity of the proposer of the transaction within the contract.

Instead, you should make the identity that is required to propose the transaction a required signer by listing them in one of the transaction's commands. Then the state cannot be issued without that identity's approval.